# Reading arduino data using python is too slow, can it speed up?

Tags: python, arduino

so I'am kinda new in programming. I'am trying to make a function to read arduino LDR data using python. If i try to print it outside of the function the data come up with a very slow speed, can anyone help please ..

I already tried to change baudrate and delay in my arduino code

```
import serial

def read_from_port():
    connected = False
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.port = 'COM3'

    while not connected:    
        #serin = ser.read()
        connected = True
        ser.open()

        while True:
            arduinoData = ser.readline()
            arduinoInt = int(arduinoData)
            return arduinoInt


while True :
    arduinoJoin = read_from_port()
    if arduinoJoin >= 101 :
            print("dark")
    if arduinoJoin <= 100 :
            print("bright")

'''
my arduino code

    void setup()

    {

    Serial.begin(9600);


    }

    void loop()

    {

    int AnalogValue;

    AnalogValue = analogRead(A0);

    Serial.println(AnalogValue);
    delay(100);

    }
'''
```

I expect the output will be as fast as the data in arduino but the truth is the data is coming up way too slow, about 1sec/data

Comment: You are reopening the serial port for every line that you read. This is quite inefficient per se. Even worse, as you are not closing the connection properly, you might run out of file descriptors. Rewrite your code to open only one connection and see whether this change solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, it is working so well.

Comment: Also note that every time you open a connection, your Arduino might be resetting - this is the behaviour for Arduino boards like the Uno and Nano.